# Branching process with varying offspring distribution at each step

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Consider a simple branching process $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2...$ such that at every discrete step, a particle splits into $k\geq1$ particles where $k$ follows a discrete distribution with probability mass $p(k)$.

From the theory of branching processes, a basic result is that the average number of particles at the $n$th step is given by:

$$\mu:=\mathbb{E}[Z_n|Z_0=1]=m^n,$$
where $m=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k p(k)$ is the mean of the offspring distribution.

#### Question

What happens to $\mu$ when the offspring distribution depends on the number of steps? That is, $p(k)\to p_n(k)$ where $n$ is a parameter that represents the number of steps.

What is the typical vocabulary to describe this generalization? I could not find this with some naive searches on google scholar.

Finally, to illustrate it with an example: Let
$$p_n(k)= p(k) e^{-\frac{k}{n}}c_n,$$

where $c_n$ is to normalise $p_n(k)$ and $p_0(k):=p(k)$. Is it still possible to express $\mu$ with a close formula?

(This question is motivated by population dynamics, where as a population grows, the number of new-borns decreases due to limited space, competition etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as terminology goes, I have seen this called "Branching process in a varying environment" and also "inhomogeneous Galton-Watson process".

Starting from one individual, the mean of $Z_n$ is simply $\prod_{i=1}^n m_i$ where $m_i$ is the mean of the offspring distribution for the $i$th generation. For example you can get this by induction using the conditional expectation $E(Z_n|Z_{n-1})=m_n Z_{n-1}$.